# VBS to open an Excel file is disabling the ribbon

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm trying to use a VBS file to open an Excel file. I like the idea because it keeps the workbook minimized during start-up. No code I've tried in the Workbook Open event is successful at doing this. Start-up takes 7-10 seconds (partly because lots of code, more because my computer is old)

The workbook's primary interface is a userform. The intent is to open with the userform visible and the workbook minimized but available at the click of a button on the userform if needed. The ribbon is also hidden, to give more real estate, but available at the click of another button if needed. As I said, with whatever code I use, the workbook won't go invisible until the start-up is finished.

I discovered the idea of using VBS here on an old thread, and it seemed to work. But when the workbook is displayed, the ribbon is disabled. Even manually inserting a line to display the ribbon does nothing. If I open the workbook directly from  the file's folder, the ribbon is available when needed. So I don't think the problem is inherent in the .xlsm.

Add here that I knew nothing about VBS code—just found it here and tried it. The code I'm using is this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\2020\2020", 0, False)
```

Is there something in this code that's disabling the ribbon, or something I need to add to *en*able it? I don't know what the zero means. I tried replacing it with 1, and then 2, but nothing seemed to change.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) you find the documentation to `Workbooks.open`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry, perhaps it's just my own ignorance, but I'm not seeing anything there that would answer my question. As nearly as I can tell this page is only about VBA, and does not even address VBS.

Comment: @NickVittum the link Storax provided has all the parameters that you can set when you call `Workbooks.Open`. Apart from some possible syntactical differences, it makes no difference whether you call it through VBA or VBS (or any other language; it is just a call on an Excel object). I dont see any that influence the ribbon.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you. I found the answer elsewhere. I needed to add the line
`xlApp.Visible = True`